# On Converging sub-series

Tags: sequences-and-series

While thinking about Riemann's rearrangement theorem, the following question struck me :

Let $a_{n}$ be a converging real sequence, such as $\sum a_{n}$ is a conditionally converging series. For all $r \in \mathbb{R}$, does there exist $I \subset \mathbb{N}$ such as $\sum_{i \in I} a_{i} \rightarrow r$ ?

If so, is $I$ unique ?

Sorry if I'm missing something trivial, I'm a theoretical physics student, not a mathematician.

EDIT : corrected a mistake : $I$ is obviously a subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Well, it seems that it won't be true for all such $r$. But, if you take a subseries, it will definitely be converging to some real number.

Comment: If so, is there a way to show it ?

Comment: Is $I$ a subset or a member of $\Bbb N$?

Comment: I is of course a subset of n

Comment: If you use "conditionally convergent" in the exact sense, and not as "conditionally or absolutely convergent", then yes, such $I$ exist for every $r$. They are not unique, there are infinitely many such $I$ for every $r$.